# URL paramater keeps adding up if I keep clicking on the page

Tags: javascript, html

My code basically adds:
`&lang=en`
or
`&lang=fr`
 to the URL, depending on which page I click on.
My problem is that URL paramater keeps adding up if I keep clicking on the page.
For example, if I click on 'English' page only once, this happens:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=en` (which is good),
However, when I click on 'English' page second time, this happens:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=en&lang=en` (which is bad).
It should be like this:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=en`
Another important example:
When I click on 'English' page, this happens:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=en` (which is good)
Then, when I go to 'France' page (after I visited 'English' page), this happens:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=en&lang=fr` (which is bad).
It should be like this:
`http://example.com/english/&lang=fr`

```js
document.getElementById("eng").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "&lang=en";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

document.getElementById("fr").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "&lang=fr";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<li><a id="eng" href="http://example.com/english/">English</a></li>
<li><a id="fr" href="http://example.com/france/">France</a></li>
```

What is the best way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You could try adding this: `if(href.includes("&lang=fr")){ location.href = href - "&lang=fr" + "&lang=en" }` and the respective counterpart when trying to change to the other language.

Comment: You probably are looking for event listener with once option. Found a link on the internet for that: https://dev.to/cilly_boloe/addeventlistener-once-js-bits-565d

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line of code:

```
location.href = href + "&lang=en";
```

`href` returns, in this case, `&lang=en`.
The above line of code adds onto the existing value of href and forwards the page to that address.

Instead, it should just be setting the value, and not incrementing it.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? I don't want to clean everything after "Page Name" in the URL and add &lang after it. I want to keep whole URL intact while still adding only ONE instance of &lang on the top of it.

Comment: I would recommend you to perhaps look at string manipulation in javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp and figure out a way to get the URL until the `lang` attribute, append the required attribute value and then forward to the address.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the updated URL with an if conditional and then 'clean it' with replace method:

```js
document.getElementById("eng").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href)

    console.log(href.includes('&lang=en'))
    if(href) {
        if(href.includes('&lang=en')){
            href.replace('&lang=en', '')
        }   
        location.href = href + "&lang=en";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

document.getElementById("fr").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        if(href.includes('&lang=fr')){
            href.replace('&lang=fr', '')
        } 
        location.href = href + "&lang=fr";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```